# how to assign a value to a variable of a return function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a function that has an assigned variable in it. looking at the example code below:

```
function a(x){   
    function b(y){
        return x+y;
    }
    return b;
}
```

executing a(4) would return the function b in this format:

```
function b(y){
    return x+y;
}
```

now how can one make so executing a(4) returns b as below:

```
function b(y){
    return 4+y;
}
```

apologies for the title didn't know quite well how to word the question.

Comment: Your code works. What's the question?

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is `a(4)(123)`, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: what i am looking for is i need to be able to call b(y) without knowing what x is later on. So i need a way to set var add4=a(4) and then be able to call var z= add4(10) to perform 4+10

Answer (score 0):

Since a(4) is what gives you b, you now need to call b(y). So if you wanted x to be 4 and y to be 5, you'd call:

```
a(4)(5) // returns 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the return value to another variable

```js
function a(x){   
    function b(y){
        return x+y;
    }
    return b;
}
var add4 = a(4);
console.log(add4(10));
var add6 = a(6);
console.log(add6(15));
```

Answer (score 0):

you code is true，use way is a(4)(3).The x in b is a's arguments.

Comment: what i am looking for is i need to be able to call b(y) without knowing what x is later on. So i need a way to set var add4=a(4) and then be able to call var z= add4(10) to perform 4+10

Comment: @M_kul,you code can do what you say,Why don't you try？

Comment: you are right this is silly i thought i had it right turns out i had a typo somewhere else completely

Comment: @M_kul Enjoy the fun of programming